# how to check if time is greater than created_at in database with carbon laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4, php-carbon

I want to write a code whereby if a user is created in my database the user must make payment. If the user does not make payment the user should be blocked. I have a column called blocked which is set to 0 by default, but if a user is blocked then its set to 1. On creation of account the created_at column is set to Carbon::now(), but if the user does not pay in 24 hours i want to block the user(i.e set the blocked column to = 1). Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

whereColumn

The whereColumn method may be used to verify that two columns are equal

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

->whereColumn('created_at','<=', Carbon::today())
```

Answer (score 10):

Use [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) methods to check if user was created more than 24 hours ago. Add this clause to the query:

```
->where('created_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subDay())
```

Don't forget to add `use` clause to the top of the class where you run the query:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

Comment: Yes. But use it without a parameter. Alternatively, you can use `subHours(24)` or `subDays(1)`

Comment: where can i get tutorials on how to  host laravel app..i want to host my app now.

Comment: @OGPaulCaleb can't help you with host tutorials, sorry. Try to google it and I'm sure you'll find some good ones.